# How to change 'Server' Header from Restlet 2.1

Tags: spring, restlet, restlet-2.0

I'am using Restlet 2.1 with Spring 3 and I need to remove the header named `Server` with value `Restlet-Framework/2.1.x`.

I know this information come from `ServerInfo.agent`. A solution I found is to change the value in the `Response` object, but it could be difficult because I had a lot of resources.
The object `Resolver` seems to be interesting, but I don't really find how to use it.

I try to find a generic solution for all my resources. Ideally only change the spring configuration and let the IoC doing the job.

Answer (score 0):

The `ServerInfo` is [set on the `SpringComponent`](https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/blob/26949cfcf9d4b281a12476f48f914c8ead355f33/modules/org.restlet.ext.spring/src/org/restlet/ext/spring/SpringComponent.java#L141). Maybe you can find the Spring Context where the `ServerInfo` instance is instanciated.